# Perl: Create directory from strings

Tags: perl

Lets suppose I have a base directory `/home/user/test/`. Now, I have two strings `a` , `b` which are going to be the folder inside the base directory like `/home/user/test/a/b`.

Currently what I am doing is:

```
use File::Path qw(make_path);

my $path = "$basedir"."/"."a"."/"."b"
make_path("$path");
```

Now, what am looking for is:

```
my $dir = "/home/user/test";
my $x = "a";
my $y = "b";

make_path($dir, $x, $y);
```

But when I run the above code instead of creating `/home/user/test/a/b` it creates two separate directory `a` and `b` in the current working directory.

So, what is the correct way to achieve this.?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an easy way to do it:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use File::Path qw(make_path);    

my $dir = "/home/user/test";
my $x = "a";
my $y = "b";

make_path(join '/',$dir,$x,$y);
```

Look up [`join`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/join.html) for more information.

Comment: I am aware of `join` but I was looking for a more elegant/general way.

Comment: @Noob, `make_path` requires a string describing the path to be created, so you are going to have to assemble the subdirectories into a single string.  `join` is the simplest way to do that.  If you want to generalize beyond two subdirectories, then store all of your subdirectories in an array and `join` the array.

Comment: Ok. I am going for this solution.

Comment: A "nicer" way to do things would be to use `File::Spec->catfile` instead of a join (to be platform agnostic) - my 2 cents.

Answer (score 3):

better use **Path::Class::Dir**

```
use Path::Class qw(dir);  # Export a short constructor

my $dir = dir('foo', 'bar');       # Path::Class::Dir object
my $dir = Path::Class::Dir->new('foo', 'bar');  # Same thing

# Stringifies to 'foo/bar' on Unix, 'foo\bar' on Windows, etc.
print "dir: $dir\n";
```

see also
    perldoc Path::Class::Dir 
or
https://metacpan.org/module/Path::Class::Dir